# Difficulty teaming up neighbours of each cone

Tags: python

I have a nested list of junctions between cones.

```
a = [0,1]
b = [2,4]
c = [2,0]
d = [4,3]

e=[a,b,c,d]
```

I want to write a program that lists every neighbour of cone 0, every neighbour of cone 1...
ie i want the output to be [[1,2],[0],[0,4],[4],[2,3]]

I did the following:

```
neighbour_list =[]
cone = 0

for element in e:

   while cone in element:

      if cone == element[0]:
        neighbour = element[1]
        neighbour_list.append(neighbour)

      else:
        neighbour = element[0]
        neighbour_list.append(neighbour)


      cone = cone + 1
 print(neighbour_list)
```

my idea was to identify lists containing cone 0, then cone 1 , then cone 2 etc and for each one extract the neighbour (ie element[1] or element[0]) and append it to neighbour_list.

i get the error message : "while cone in element" - argument of type (int) not iterable

whats wrong?

Comment: It's best if you post the complete traceback (in a code block).  I do not get the error you mentioned - it runs without error, v2.7.

Comment: sorry my bad this running it i obtain [1, 0, 4, 4, 3] do you get it as well? however this is wrong its not what i am looking for

Comment: could you let me know whats wrong please? @wwii

Comment: Each time you append to ```neighbor_list``` you only append a single element.  You want to *accumulate* all the neighbors of each cone in a list then append that list to the neighbor_list.  I'm not sure you can fix your current code.  You might try iterating through the *cones* in the outer loop and ```elements``` in the inner loop - then you can find all the neighbors for ```cone``` 0 then ```cone``` 1 ...

Comment: @wwii oh ok I understand its only taking one neighbour into account because of cone = cone + 1 it moves on to the next cone.what do you call inner and outer loop? would i still keep "while cone in element" loop ?

Comment: Yep, you have *nested loops* and ```while cone in element:``` is the inner loop.  You should edit your question to state what the problem is (not the error) and maybe refine the question so it is not a general `what's wrong`.  Spending some time defining the question/problem can help you understand it.

Comment: @wwii i have trouble identifiying what the inner loop would be. considering we want to loop through elements and cones I figured I should have element = element + 1 at the end of inner loop and cone = cone + 1 at the end of outer loop. but what is the inner loop? while element...? thanks

Comment: What does "cone" mean here?

Comment: @ChrisMartin cone is either 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.                         a = [0,1]
b = [2,4]
c = [2,0]
d = [4,3]  all represent junctions between cones. eg a tells us that cone 0 and cone 1 have a junction

Comment: Sorry, still confused - why are you calling those numbers cones? I've never heard this terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a dictionary instead.

```
a = [0, 1]
b = [2, 4]
c = [2, 0]
d = [4, 3]

e = [a, b, c, d]
neighbour_list = {}

for x, y in e:
    neighbour_list.setdefault(x, [])
    neighbour_list[x].append(y)
    neighbour_list.setdefault(y, [])
    neighbour_list[y].append(x)
neighbour_list = list(neighbour_list.values())
print(neighbour_list)
```

Running it gives:

```
[[1, 2], [0], [4, 0], [4], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: setdefault is described in the docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault -- In this program it looks to see if there's an entry for key x in the dictionary yet. If not, it will fill in x with an empty list, so that we can populate it with values. btw, if you like my answer, please click the green checkmark. :)

Comment: thanks @twasbrillig it prints dict_values([[1, 2], [0], [4, 0], [4], [2, 3]]) what if i want the result to be printed without "dict_values" written is this possible and how?

Comment: ah, you're right, it does that in Python 3. You just need to change the line `neighbour_list = neighbour_list.values()` to `neighbour_list = list(neighbour_list.values())`. I edited the code above to make this change.

Comment: if i add f = [4,6] and change e=[a,b,c,d] to e=[a,b,c,d,f] it prints [[1, 2], [0], [4, 0], [4], [2, 3, 6], [4]] Yet we can notice cone 5 is not included. cone 5 has no neighbours so should be [...[2, 3, 6], [], [4]] what would I have to change for it to print neighbour list even if a cone has no neighbours? @twasbrillig

Comment: Hi Hannah, you haven't voted up my answer and didn't mark the green checkmark, that means you didn't like the answer...I'm hesitant to keep working on it unless you do one or both of the above...

Comment: new on website so I have no idea how to do it? @twasbrillig

Answer (score 0):

Using descriptive names will help make your code more *readable*.

```
a = [0,1]
b = [2,4]
c = [2,0]
f = [4,6]
junctions=[a,b,c,d,f]
neighbour_list =[]
```

If we didn't know in advance what the cones were, we would need to find all the cones in the junctions

```
# find all the cones in the junctions
cones = list()
for junction in junctions:
    for cone in junction:
        cones.append(cone)
# The previous could be replaced with a list comprehension
# cones = [cone for junction in junctions for cone in junction]
```

If you want to only consider cones that have junctions use

```
##cones = set(cones)
```

If you want to consider all cones within the range represented in the junctions use

```
cones = range(min(cones), max(cones) + 1)
```

It is a bit easier to build the lists if the *cone* loop is the outer loop  because we are trying to find the neighbours for each cone:

```
# for each cone look through the junctions to find neighbors
for cone in sorted(cones):    #search for neighbors from the smallest to the largest cone
    neighbors = list()    #make a new list for each cone
    for junction in junctions:
        if junction[0] == cone:
            neighbors.append(junction[1])
        elif junction[1] == cone:
            neighbors.append(junction[0])
    neighbour_list.append(neighbors)

>>> print neighbour_list
[[1, 2], [0], [4, 0], [4], [2, 3, 6], [], [4]]
>>>
```

It seems like neighbour_list is missing some information - you can't readily tell which cone the neighbors are for.  You could use `zip` to add the information:

```
>>> print zip(sorted(cones), neighbour_list)
[(0, [1, 2]), (1, [0]), (2, [4, 0]), (3, [4]), (4, [2, 3, 6]), (5, []), (6, [4])]
>>>
```

Or a slight change in the program could add the info neighbour_list

```
neighbour_list.append((cone,neighbors))
```

Comment: if i add f = [4,6] and change junctions=[a,b,c,d] to junctions=[a,b,c,d,f] it prints [[1, 2], [0], [4, 0], [4], [2, 3, 6], [4]] Yet we can notice cone 5 is not included. cone 5 has no neighbours so should be [...[2, 3, 6], [], [4]] what would I have to change for it to print neighbour list even if a cone has no neighbours? @wwii

Comment: Do you understand how it works?  Did you spot the anomaly in the code or did you try it with that test case and notice it didn't meet expectations? If that result for that test case is part of the spec, you should update the question. Your spec should state that there should be an item in ```neighbour_list``` for each possible cone within the range of cones represented in the junctions.